# Equal string comparison returning false

Tags: javascript, string, compare

When executing the command `==` between 2  equal string's I am getting the return false.

The following code:

somewhere in the code:

```
Arr.prod.push({
                 "id" : product.id,
                 "nameProd" : product.name
    });
```

In other local at code:

```
var id;
for(i in Arr.prod){
   if( $.trim(str) == $.trim(Arr.prod[i].nameProd)){
        id = Arr.prod[i].id;
    break;
    }
}
```

when `i = 3`, the value of `Array.prod[i].nameProd` is equal of `str` value. The value of these variables is:  "DVD Player Automotivo CED229X - Tela 3, Entrada USB Frontal, Entrada SD Flip Down e Controle Remoto - Philips - Philips - Americ ...". But the comparison always returns false.

What is wrong?

**EDIT**

adding code in for iteration:

```
console.log( 'str = ' + $.trim(str).toLowerCase(), ', item = ' + 
$.trim(Arr.prod[i].nameProd).toLowerCase(), 'result = ' + 
($.trim(str).toLowerCase() == $.trim(Arr.prod[i].nameProd).toLowerCase()));
```

**RESULT**

> str = dvd player automotivo ced229x - tela 3'', entrada usb frontal,
>   entrada sd flip down e controle remot ... , item = tv 46" led full hd
>   (1920 x 1080 pixels) - 46pfl7606d/78 - smart tv ambilight spectra 2,
>   online tv, c ... result = false
>
> str = dvd player automotivo ced229x - tela 3'', entrada usb frontal,
>   entrada sd flip down e controle remot ... , item = home theater c/ dvd
>   - 250 w rms, hdmi,divx, usb - hts3510/78 - philips - philips - americanas.com.br result = false
>
> str = dvd player automotivo ced229x - tela 3'', entrada usb frontal,
>   entrada sd flip down e controle remot ... , item = notebook hp result
>   = false
>
> str = dvd player automotivo ced229x - tela 3'', entrada usb frontal,
>   entrada sd flip down e controle remot ... , item = tenis rebook result
>   = false
>
> str = dvd player automotivo ced229x - tela 3'', entrada usb frontal,
>   entrada sd flip down e controle remot ... , item = dvd player
>   automotivo ced229x - tela 3'', entrada usb frontal, entrada sd flip
>   down e controle remot ... result = false

The last comparison should be true

**look this**

```
console.log('str : ' + escape(str));
console.log('arr : ' + escape(Arr.prod[i].nameProd)));
```

RESULT:

```
str : DVD%20Player%20Automotivo%20CED229X%20-%20Tela%203%27%27%2C%20Entrada%20USB%20Frontal%2C%20Entrada%20SD%20Flip%20Down%20e%20Controle%20Remot%20...

arr : DVD%20Player%20Automotivo%20CED229X%20-%20Tela%203%27%27%2C%20Entrada%20USB%20Frontal%2C%20Entrada%20SD%20Flip%20Down%A0e%20Controle%20Remot%20...
```

look after "Down" word in 2 log's:

In str contains %20e%, as in arr contains %A0e%.

What is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Put a `console.log( $.trim(str), $.trim(Array.prod[i].nameProd), $.trim(str) == $.trim(Array.prod[i].nameProd) );` between the for and if lines. And tell us what comes up.

Comment: Also probably not the cause of error, but why do you use the Array constructor function (as a namespace or whatever)?

Comment: Please try to reproduce this with http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: could you provide the array? or could you check what you get when adding `console.log($.trim(str))` and `console.log($.trim(Array.prod[i].nameProd))` before the if?

Comment: All, updated the code. Look Now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you code is generating a non-breaking space (ascii 160 or A0) after the word "Down" thus the `%A0`.

Why this happens i have no clue, but that is what you need to fix.

If you cannot figure out how to fix this problem, then you can at least treat the symptom by replacing the non-breaking spaces with normal spaces before comparison, like this:

```
$.trim(str).replace(/\xa0/g,' ') == $.trim(Arr.prod[i].nameProd.replace(/\xa0/g,' '))
```

Comment: Interesting.

The variable str is a substring of a message sent to facebook by "request dialog" (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). In a moment, I request message back for processing (using FQL - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ in table apprequest(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/apprequest/) in column MESSAGE). I apply substring in message, then insert in str variable. Probably facebook changed encode of the message.

There a way to "normalize" all string to especific encode? For example, 'UTF-8'?

Comment: It's not a charset problem, the characters are actually different. conversion from one charset to anoteher will not make non-breaking spaces into normal spaces afaik.

Comment: Correct. So the only solution is proposed above?

Comment: There are always other solutions, the question is whether this one will satisfy you or not. If not, keep looking :)